# Firestore query on sub-collection doesn't return data

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a database with the following structure in Firestore:

users/{user document}/requests/{request document}

EDIT:  I added a screenshot of my firebase console showing the data.  A little hard to see but you can tell that the record for the user as well as the request exist.  You should also be able to see the 'path'.  I hope that helps.

I need to query the requests collection for a particular user (so this is not a CollectionGroup thing).  I'm using Angular Firebase and try the following

```
var ref = db.collection("users").doc("0g0ujmsgdTa7NgaJPUV5ULjumIV2").collection("requests")

var result = await ref.where("to","==","frank").get();
console.log(result.size);
```

This returns a result of zero records (where the presence of the user document has been confirmed (that long string) and that multiple documents in the requests collection contain the field 'to' which is set to 'frank'.

By all accounts this should work.  I've tried many other queries like pulling down all the records of the requests collection (meaning a get() on the requests collection), and it works.  I've tried similar queries on the user collection (with data relevant to users) and that works.

Is there anything I can try to trouble shoot why this would happen?

[image]

Comment: Since we can't see the data in your database, we don't know if you're making a query that's actually supposed to return anything.  Please edit the question to explain in more detail what exactly you're expecting from this query, showing examples of documents that should match.  A screenshot of data would help.

Comment: This should return 3 documents.  There are about 8,800 request documents for this user but only 3 have 'to' set to 'frank'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data you're trying to query is nested as a field under a map field called "inRequest".  You need to identify the **full path** of this field for querying using [dot notation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_fields_in_nested_objects):

```
var ref = db
    .collection("users")
    .doc("0g0ujmsgdTa7NgaJPUV5ULjumIV2")
    .collection("requests")
var result = await ref
    .where("inRequest.to", "==", "frank")
    .get();
console.log(result.size);
```

Note the first argument to `where()`.

Comment: So first, thank you!  This does work.  I'll need to dig in a little to understand exactly why.  In my defense (or at least I think this backs up what I was trying to do):    https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#node.js_1

Comment: Sorry, one more comment.  I've noted the presence of this 'inRequest' wrapper and am wondering if this is new and if not why it doesn't seem to appear in the docs.  For others looking at this, it's important to note that Firebase returns your document, but it's wrapped in an inRequest object.

Comment: inRequest exists because something wrote it there.  It's not part of Firestore - it's written data.  You'll have to find the code that wrote it and fix it if that's not what you want.

Comment: lol, now I'm red faced.  I see now where I'm writing it that way.  Thank you again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

based on documentation and if my understanding is correct you should do

```
var myCollection = db.collection("users").doc("0g0ujmsgdTa7NgaJPUV5ULjumIV2").collection("requests", ref => ref.where('to', '==', 'frank'))
myCollection.get().subscribe((response) => console.log(response))
```

`where` is not a method of `firebase.firestore.collection` rather one of `firebase.firestore.CollectionReference.`

also you won't get anything more than an `Observable` using `get()` method

(not tested)

**REFERENCE**

[documentation](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/querying-collections.md)

Comment: So on this, when I try to implement in my code I get 'expected 1 argument but go 2' on the 'ref' function (being passed into collection).  It doesn't like that second argument.  I'm not sure if this is relevant but I'm doing this in a cloud function in Firebase.

Comment: @user1684600 aren't you using angularfire?